# Redirect to a post with specific name from user input in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am a newbie in RoR, thus sorry for stupid question :(
I have a **Game model**, with a **code** string. There is a welcome/index view in my app with a simple form_to input. I wish to redirect user to a Game with a specific code after he submits the form.
I understand that I should somehow combine a **.where** method and **redirect_to** in Welcome_controller, but I just can't figure out how...

Welcome_controller.rb:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def redirect
    redirect_to ?game with a code that equals :param from input?
 end
end
```

Welcome/index:

```
<h1>Let's join the game!</h1>

<%= form_tag redirect_path do %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:param) %>  
   <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :games
  get 'games/index'

  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

game.rb:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

games_controller:

```
PREFACE      = ('A'..'Z').to_a << ?_
SUFFIX       = ('0'..'9').to_a
PREFACE_SIZE = 2
SUFFIX_SIZE  = 3

class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /games or /games.json
  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  # GET /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /games/new
  def new
    @game = Game.new
    @game.code = gen_name
  end

  def gen_name
    PREFACE.sample(PREFACE_SIZE).join << SUFFIX.sample(SUFFIX_SIZE).join
  end

  # GET /games/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /games or /games.json
  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to game_url(@game), notice: "Game was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.update(game_params)
        format.html { redirect_to game_url(@game), notice: "Game was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def destroy
    @game.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to games_url, notice: "Game was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_game
      @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:code, :name)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add some code over here?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I edited the question)

Comment: Is it resolved or still facing issues?

Comment: I resolved this issue in a slightly different way than I thought :) I will write a possible solution here tomorrow for the future generations)

Answer (score 0):

In `config/routes.rb` you have defined `resources :games`, which creates default paths for CRUD actions. For the show action, which you are trying to get here, it would lead to `/games/:id` and the helper method would be `game_path`. You can also check this by running `rails routes -c games` command in the app directory. It should return all paths for `games_controller`

In the `before_action` callback for `GamesController#show` action, you are finding a Game object using `Game.find(params[:id])`. `:id` parameter is what you need to pass to the path helper that I mentioned earlier for the action to fire properly, so the path to a specific game would look like `game_path(id: game.id)`. This will then automatically get converted to params. Alternatively, you can just pass the game object to the path helper and it will do the job for you like this: `game_path(game)`

Now in the `WelcomeController#redirect` action, you get the game code in params from the form submit. You need to first find the game for the submitted code like this:

```rb
game = Game.find_by(code: params[:param])
```

This should work if the code is unique for each game. Now that you have the correct game record, all you need is to redirect to the path that I've mentioned eariler:

```rb
redirect_to game_path(game)
```